# Is it possible to prevent Android Studio from downloading older SDKs automatically when opening older projects?

Tags: android-studio

Let's say you're using API 29 for your current project.  You open an older project to see how you did something, which used API 28.  Android Studio starts automatically downloading everything you need for the older project to build, including the entire API 28 SDK.  Is it possible to prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 0):

Edit the `build.gradle` with any other text editor, before opening it as a project in Android Studio.

About the same applies for Gradle wrapper versions.